# Checkbox color change to gray

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I need to change the whole check box in gray color. Basic idea behind changing the check box color to show as a placeholder, all other control is shown in gray except the check box.

Can you please suggest easy way to make it .

Comment: What do you mean by whole check box? including label?

Comment: No, Just checkbox border and tick mark.

Comment: You can check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to use background Images because checkboxes are not able to be styled because browsers usually overwrite the checkbox styles. http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-checkbox-radio/

Another way is to use a third party js plugin there are many available.
http://www.sitepoint.com/15-jquery-radio-button-checkbox-style-plugins/

Comment: Thanks !  http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-checkbox-radio/ it is helpful to me. You have saved my life time.

Comment: YEY! I'm glad, and you pushed my reputation over 100 :)  Win Win!

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you're looking for the disabled option while you're writing the code or your greying out the check box after a condition.

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />
```